# handle json key value(which is again dict) to a list, xlsxwriter is not accepting dict

Tags: json, python-3.x, xlsxwriter

I have a situation where in json key value has a dict.
Perviously I had just a string or integer or float for a key value.
I could able to take all values to a list and populate in excel using xlsxwriter module using Python:

```
names = list(data['items'][]['variants'].values())
```

Now my json key value has dict:

```
"foobar": {
    "agents": {
        "scenario": {
            "capacity": {
                "add": [
                    "sample"
                ],
                "signal": [
                    "all"
                ]
            },
            "eligibility": true,
            "read": false,
            "runAsUser": 0
        }
    },
```

Because of this my script is throwing below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/virtualenvs/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xlsxwriter/worksheet.py", line 493, in _write
    f = float(token)
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'dict'
..............
.......................
.......................
    raise TypeError("Unsupported type %s in write()" % type(token))
TypeError: Unsupported type <class 'dict'> in write()
```

Is there any way that we can handle this situation.
My goal is to capture that dict and put into a list and populate to excel.

Comment: You just need to iterate through the dict and write the dat you want cell by cell. There is an example in the [XlsxWriter docs](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_data.html#writing-dicts-of-data) for a simpler dict structure. However, the structure you show above has 5 levels of data so you will need to think a bit about how you want to display that on a 2D worksheet in Excel.

Comment: thanks for your quick response @jmcnamara ......... the second level is a key for me and rest of the structure below is value. I want that entire value to be an element in list. that each element should be populated to cells in excel

Comment: It would be good to update your question with a screenshot from Excel of how you would like it to look. That will make it easier to answer.

Answer (score 1):

Finally resolved issue using map:

```
names = list(map(json.dumps, data['items'][varients]['names'].values()))
```